# Why my 1-D histograms are not showing correcctly?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, histogram, sequence

I have two sets of data (x, y) corresponding to two 1-D histograms that are meant to be plotted next to each other as subplots. Both x and y values are different and hence they would be represented in different axes. The histogram heights (first item in hists) and the corresponding sequence of bins (second items in hists) are given for each subplot as the following:

*Please note that each height correspond to the bin in the sequence; heights are already known for each bin. I just want to put data in a bar format using hist function

```
array_1 = np.array([ 8.20198063, 8.30645018, 8.30829034, 8.63297701, 0., 0., 10.43478942])
array_random_1 = np.array([ 8.23460584, 8.31556503, 8.3090378, 8.63147021, 0., 0., 10.41481862])
array_2 = np.array([10.4348338, 8.69943553, 8.68710347, 6.67854038])
array_random_2 = np.array([10.41597028, 8.76635268, 8.19516216, 6.68126994])
bins_1, bins_2 = [8.0, 8.6, 9.2, 9.8, 10.4, 11.0, 11.6, 12.2], [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
```

Here is my try to plot these two subplots using hist function from python:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(12,3))

ax1.hist(array_1,    bins_1, ec='blue', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='1')
ax1.hist(array_random_1, bins_1, ec='red', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='Random_1')
ax1.set_xlabel('X1')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y1')

ax2.hist(array_2,    bins_2, ec='blue', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='2')
ax2.hist(array_random_2, bins_2, ec='red', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='Random_2')
ax2.set_xlabel('X2')

plt.show()
```

However, as you can see bars are not drawn to the correct height (blue bars are missing entirely) in left-side panel and everything is missing from the second panel. What is the issue in making these 1d histograms? Does this mean that I cannot use hist for my purpose?
[image: Figure]

What I want is the following which is doable using `bar`. How to do it using `hist`?

[image: Correct Figure]

Answer (score 1):

By what I understood.

In your code try replacing:

`histtype='step'`

with

`histtype='bar'`

Comment: in that case, can you share the type of output you are expecting?

Comment: I did it using bar in the above. I wish I could do it using hist.

Comment: @Ash what does orange and blue bar represent?